# Xcode allow user to input image

Tags: xcode, image

How would you go about allowing the user to input an image in an Xcode app on iPhone?
For example setting a profile picture, where the actual user chooses the image from their photo library (or take picture etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To pick a photo, you'll need a [PHPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerviewcontroller).

This documentation page should help to understand how to use it: [Selecting Photos and Videos in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/selecting_photos_and_videos_in_ios).

The easiest way to take a picture is to present a [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) with the `sourceType` of `.camera`.